# Bad Format frozenlayout-right with SB admin

Tags: jquery, html, css, primefaces

I'm trying to integrate scrolling data-table in SB Admin template referenced by https://startbootstrap.com/themes/sb-admin-2/

That's ok in a simple html page.

But, I encounter an arbitrary space when using the data-table is included under SB Admin template.

I got that:

[image: Bad Format]

Could you please tell me what I missed, knowing that my html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <style>
            body 
            {
                background-image: url('../resources/icons/espingj.png')
            }
        </style>
    </h:head> 
    <h:body>
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <center>
            <h:outputText value="Enquête de Satisfaction pour la classe " style="color:red;font-size: 20px"/>  
            <h:outputText value=" #{manageBean.connectedUser.classecourantet}" style="color:#0000ff;font-size: 20px"/>
        </center>
        <br/>
        <div align="right">
            <h:outputText value="Veuillez exprimé votre satisfaction:" style="color:blue;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;"/>
            <p:spacer width="5px"/> 
            <h:outputText value="I-" style="color:red;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;"/>
            <h:outputText value="Insatisfait" style="color:red;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic"/>
            <p:spacer width="10px"/>              
            <h:outputText value="O-" style="color:grey;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;"/>
            <h:outputText value="Ordinaire" style="color:grey;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic"/>
            <p:spacer width="10px"/>              
            <h:outputText value="S-" style="color:green;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;"/>
            <h:outputText value="Satisfait" style="color:green;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic"/>
            <br/><br/>
            <h:form id="drawDataTable">
               <h:outputText value="(*) Merci de terminer votre procesus de satisfaction !." 
                             rendered="#{manageBean.phase2 eq 'avoid'}" update="@all"
                             style="color:red;font-size: 13px;font-style: italic;font-weight: bold;"/>

                <h:outputScript target="drawDataTable"> 
                    $(function()
                    {
                        synchronizeRowsHeight();
                    });

                    function synchronizeRowsHeight()
                    { 
                        var $leftRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-left').find('tr');
                        var $rightRows = $('.ui-datatable-frozenlayout-right').find('tr');

                        $leftRows.each(function(index)
                        {
                            var $leftRow = $(this);
                            var $leftHeight = $leftRow.innerHeight();
                            var $rightRow = $rightRows.eq(index);
                            var $rightHeight = $rightRow.innerHeight();

                            if ($rightHeight > $leftHeight)
                            {
                                $leftRow.innerHeight($rightHeight);
                                var diff = $rightHeight - $leftRow.innerHeight();
                                if (diff != 0)
                                $leftRow.innerHeight($rightHeight + diff);
                                $(window).trigger('resize');
                            } 
                            $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").height(totalHeight-50);
                        })
                    } 
                </h:outputScript> 

                <p:dataTable var="criteria" value="#{manageBean.lnomFourthCriterions}" id="data4"
                             scrollable="true" scrollWidth="695" frozenColumns="1"
                             resizableColumns="true" styleClass="fixed-size"
                             tableStyle="width: auto; white-space: nowrap;">
                    <p:columnGroup type="frozenHeader" id="aa">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Critères &#10; d'enseignement" escape="false" style="white-space:pre-line;"/>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>

                    <p:columnGroup type="scrollableHeader" id="bb">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="#{manageBean.yearCount}" headerText="#{manageBean.lcs.get(18).value}" />
                        </p:row>
                        <p:row>
                            <ui:repeat value="#{manageBean.lms}" var="module">
                                <p:column headerText="#{manageBean.findModuleByCode(module)}" style="font-size: 10px;"/>
                            </ui:repeat>
                         </p:row>
                    </p:columnGroup>

                    <p:column width="10px" style="height: 50px">
                        <h:outputText value="#{criteria.libelleNom}" style="font-size: 12px"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:columns value="#{manageBean.lms}" var="module" width="1000px" style="font-size: 12px; height:50px">
                        <center>
                            <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="choices" required="true"
                                             style="font-size: 11px;color:#737373;font-weight: normal;width:50%"
                                             value="#{manageBean.selectedItemPriorityEnseignement}"
                                             rendered="#{manageBean.getDisplaySelectedPriorityForEnseignement(criteria.abi.codeNom, module) eq null}">
                                <f:selectItems value="#{manageBean.getSelectItemsEnseignement(module)}"/>
                                <p:ajax update="drawDataTable" listener="#{manageBean.checkPriorityEns(criteria.abi.codeNom, manageBean.selectedItemPriorityEnseignement, module)}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>

                            <p:spacer width="10px"/>

                            <h:outputText value="#{manageBean.getDisplaySelectedPriorityForEnseignement(criteria.abi.codeNom, module)}" 
                                          style="color:#0066ff;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;" rendered="#{manageBean.colorCellule(module) mod 2 == 0}"/>
                                          <h:outputText value="#{manageBean.getDisplaySelectedPriorityForEnseignement(criteria.abi.codeNom, module)}" 
                                          style="color:#00ccff;font-size: 13px;font-weight: bold;" rendered="#{manageBean.colorCellule(module) mod 2 != 0}"/>

                            <p:spacer width="20px"/>
                        </center>
                    </p:columns>
                </p:dataTable>          

                <center>
                    <br/><br/><br/>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:column>
                            <p:commandLink id="pre" action="secondPhase?faces-redirect=true">
                                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/previous.png" style="width: 62px;height: 43px;"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
                            <p:tooltip for="pre" value="Précédant" style="font-size: 10px;" position="left"/>
                        </h:column>

                        <h:column>
                            <p:commandLink id="sui" ajax="true">
                                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/icons/next.png" style="width: 50px;height: 30px;"/>
                                <p:ajax update="@all" listener="#{manageBean.validatePhase2Step()}"/>
                            </p:commandLink>
                            <p:tooltip for="sui" value="Suivant" style="font-size: 10px;" position="right"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </center>

                <br/><br/><br/>
            </h:form>
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's up with the 1000px width

Comment: I don't think `ui:repeat` in a `p:row` does anything useful, on the contrary.

Comment: please share all the above code

Comment: Hello Sir @DumbCoder7, thanks for your reply, but got same issue.

Comment: Hello Sir @Kukeltje, thanks for your reply, but I need that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,
It's clear that is a problem with

- width on --> try to specify the width of column like that : 
  `<p:column rowspan="2" headerText="Critères &#10; d'enseignements" style="white-space:pre-line; width: 500px;"/>`
- p:spacer --> try to remove all p:spacer under p:column, it's unuseful

Hope Helping

Comment: that is it. thanks a lot @Saria. It's working well for me